# Употребление слова "отозвался"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли отозваться о человеке нелицеприятно непосредственно самому человеку? Например, "Федя догнал Петю и отозвался о нем нехорошо" (читай - обругал). Или все же такое построение некорректно и это слово уже предполагает наличие третьего лица, которому отзываются о человеке? "До Феди дошли слухи, что Петя отозвался о нем нехорошо".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое употребление слова неверно: *о человеке* отзываются (напр. хорошо или плохо), сообщая что-то о нём **другим** людям.

В другом значении ("ответить") слово употребляется в ситуации, когда кого-то *зовут* издалека, иногда даже не видя того, к кому обращаются. Тогда тот, кого зовут, *отзывается*, давая понять, что услышал обращение. В этом случае третьи лица не нужны.

Comment: Большое спасибо за пояснение!